# How to escape % in emacs

Tags: w3m, format

I'm trying to add a search engine in emacs-w3m and use duckduckgo to search emacswiki

```el
(eval-after-load "w3m-search"
  '(progn
     (setq w3m-search-engine-alist
           (append '(
                     ("emacswiki" "https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%s++site%3Aemacswiki.org&ia=web" nil)
                     ))
                     )))
```

It does not work as intended because of the second "%". How can we escape the % character in emacs?

Comment: Please note that `progn` and `append` are both useless in this specific snippet. I guess it was trimmed down from some real code. Also note that a recent emacs will allow the use of `with-eval-after-load`, which looks nicer (no need for a `progn` and no need to quote the form).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess internally this uses the function 'format' so you can use %% to produce one %

Comment: Thanks for the formatting. Will keep it in mind next time.